# Python define function in __init___

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project but I'm having trouble with functions in classes. To simplify the problem, here's a more simple question :

I would like to define differently a function, depending of what the "object" is. Here's an example :

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

        if(self.name=="My Name"):
            def who(self):
                print("Me")
        else:
            def who(self):
                print("Not Me")

house1=house("My Name")
house1.who()
#Expect : "Me"

house2=house("Not My Name")
house2.who()
#Expect : "Not Me"
```

In my project the functions are more useful than here and so the following solution **isn't a solution for me** :

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

        if(self.name=="My Name"):
           self.who="Me"
        else:
           self.who="Not Me"
```

Thanks for your help,

Cordially,

Thomas

Comment: As I understood from your question, the two functions will have the same name. Then, I think you should  create just one function that takes an instance of the object as input. Not to define two functions. Second, may I ask you why you want to define it inside `__init__`? why not outside it?

Comment: If there a solution defining the function outside `__init__`it would also be a solution for me...

Comment: I've added my answer, hopefully this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is improper Python, you're better off having the 'if' in your `who()` function, but if this is not an option, here is how you would do it:

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

        if(self.name=="My Name"):
            def who(self):
                print("Me")
        else:
            def who(self):
                print("Not Me")
        self.who = lambda: who(self) # You need to pass self to the who function, or else it will raise a name error
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        if (self.name == "My Name"):
            def who():
                print("Me")
        else:
            def who():
                print("Not Me")

        self.who = who
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however what if he needs access to `self` in his `who()` function, so that it can do more than just print characters?

Comment: @User12692182 it's in the closure so it can be used normally.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you have if statement inside the def like this:

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        def who():
          if(self.name == "My Name"):
            print("My Name")
          else:
            print("Not Me")

        self.who = who

house1=house("My Name")
house1.who()
```

Comment: I agree, but I'm guessing OP is concerned about checking the `if` every time. However if you're going to do this, just define it as a normal method.

Answer (score 0):

As understood from the comments of the question, the original poster was looking for the best way to define `who()` method. So, I think this is the least confusing design for such a function where you define it outside the `__init__()`.

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def who(self):
        if(self.name == "My Name"):
            print("Me")
        else:
            print("Not Me")

house1=house("My Name")
house1.who()
#Expect : "Me"

house2=house("Not My Name")
house2.who(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define both as private methods and assign to self when you know which one you want. The private method is really just a name mangled method meant to discourage access outside of the class

```
class house:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

        if(self.name=="My Name"):
            self.who = self.__who_me
        else:
            self.who = self.__who_not_me

    def __who_me(self):
        print("Me")

    def __who_not_me(self):
        print("Not Me")


house1=house("My Name")
house1.who()
#Expect : "Me"

house2=house("Not My Name")
house2.who()
#Expect : "Not Me"
```